# Why am I getting the "Clear screen capability required" when spawning screen with TERM=dumb?

Tags: python-3.x, pexpect

This is how I spawn the pexpect module.

```
os.environ["TERM"] = "dumb"
child = pexpect.spawn(
  '/usr/bin/screen -S idle nodejs botxxx/{}'.format(session["username"]+".js"),
  encoding='utf-8', env = {"TERM": "dumb"}, dimensions=(200, 200))
```

I'm looking at the pexpect output ---> Clear screen capability is required.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GNU screen` deals with pty and it requires a more powerful terminal type. So replace `dumb` with something like `xterm`.

```
$ TERM=dumb screen -S tmp
Clear screen capability required.
```

Comment: You said worked. A different problem has occurred. I edited the question. Could this be causing the problem?

Comment: this is not how SO works. when you update your Q by asking another Q you're actually invalidating the accepted answer. please rollback and ask a new Q.